# Does Leray Spectral sequence degenerates at $E_2$ over product of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, spectral-sequences, curves-and-surfaces

Let $C$ be a smooth, projective curve (can assume to be rational) and $X:=C \times C$. Denote by $p:X \to C$ one of the two natural projections. Let $E$ be a vector bundle on $X$. Is it true that,

$$H^1(E)=H^1(p_*E) \oplus H^0(R^1p_*E)?$$

i.e., the corresponding Leray spectral sequence degrenerates at $E_2$?

Comment: Yes: $E^{pq}_2=0$ if $p>1$ or $q>1$ and the differential has degree $(2, -1)$. Right?

Comment: Two remarks: 1) That would be true for any morphism of any variety $X$ onto a curve $C$.     2) Note however that the splitting is not canonical.

Comment: @abx and Piotr: Thanks for the answer.